# Bezier curves have different diameter when applying round bevel property

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I have made a few Bezier curves. When I go to object data properties-> geometry -> bevel -> round(option) and say 0.04 m thickness, the resulting bevels are of different diameter for different bezier curves. The scale is set to 1 for all of them. I am not sure why, could you guys help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

You must have scaled some of them, then applied the scale, in that case you need to make sure that the radius of the vertices is set to 1: Switch to *Edit* mode, select all the vertices and right click > *Set Curve Radius > 1* (you can also check and change the curve radius in the *N* panel):

[image]